# Can a class constructor return a child class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to build a class which will parse mathematical expressions (I'm aware of SymPy, I've tried it but it isn't appropriate to my uses).

Depending on the expression input, I need to return a different class. As an example, I have this:

```py
class MyNum(MyTerm):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.num = n

    def latex(self):
        return str(self.num)


class MyDivision(MyTerm):
    def __init__(self, n, d):
        self.numerator = n
        self.denominator = d

    def latex(self):
        return '\\frac {{ {} }} {{ {} }}'.format(self.numerator, self.denominator)


def parseTerm(term):
    matches = re.match(r'^[0-9]+$', term)
    if matches is not None:
        return MyNum(term)

    matches = re.match(r'^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$', term)
    if matches is not None:
        return MyDivision(matches[1], matches[2])
```

So we have a factory function `parseTerm`, which will return the appropriate class. `parseTerm("2")` will give a `MyNum`, while `parseTerm("2/3")` will give a `MyDivision`.

I built this on advice from another question which suggested that classes should never return a different function. But the more I think about it, the more unsatisfied I am. Every class will implement exactly the same outward-facing methods, and the question of which one you're left with is an implementation detail. It seems to me appropriate that a user would call `num = MyTerm("2")` and get whichever child class is appropriate, and calling a function instead of instantiating a class adds confusion.

I welcome criticisms for how my reasoning is wrong since I'm going against advice, but my technical question is: how do I actually do it? How does a class constructor return a different class?

Comment: I would say creating an object and getting something else would create confusion. Calling a function/method doesn’t. Even if it were possible I would never do it like that.

Comment: Can you share the definition of `MyTerm`

Comment: The current code is fine, the only thing you can gain by complicating is more bugs - in the end the client code will still look like a function invocation resulting in some class instance.

Comment: I would say just implementing a `Parser` class which takes care of parsing a term and returning the correct `MyTerm` subclass should be enough. Check if my answer makes sense @wyatt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with `__new__`, but the added functionality is not worth the complexity.

The naive:

```
class MyTerm:
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        return parseTerm(*args)
```

would fail with a `RecursionError` because the creation of a subclass object (in `ParseTerm` would call... `MyTerm.__new__`!

Ok, let us just delegate to `object` for subclasses:

```
class MyTerm:
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if cls is MyTerm:
            return parseTerm(*args)
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

It will work for `"2"`, not for `"4/2"`, because `MyDivision.__init__` is called twice:

- first time from inside `parseTerm` with arguments "4", "2"
- second time by Python machinery after `MyTerm.__new__` with the original argument "4/2"

So you will have to allow `MyDivision.__init__` to accept and ignore that call:

```
class MyDivision(MyTerm):
    def __init__(self, n, d = None):
        print(self, n, d)
        if d is not None:
            self.numerator = n
            self.denominator = d
```

But that would allow `MyDivision("4")`... So a new test:

```
class MyDivision(MyTerm):
    def __init__(self, n, d = None):
        print(self, n, d)
        if d is not None:
            self.numerator = n
            self.denominator = d
        if not hasattr(self, denominator):
            raise TypeError("Missing required argument")
```

IMHO, it is not worth it...

Comment: The dangers of ignoring advice. You're right, I missed a lot of the complexity this would entail. Thank you.

Comment: Will adding the `Parser` class as I mentioned in my answer help in any way @wyatt @serge-ballesta

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: I do not think so. The constructor of a class is expected to build objects of that class, full stop. Any attempt to act differently will end in a terrible hack with caveats all around.

Comment: Aah, so instead of putting a `parseTerm`, returning the class object in `__init__` would work for `Parser` class?

Answer (score 1):

You should just call a function that performs the logic you need for determining which class should be returned, and return that child class. In this case, `num = parseTerm("2")`, would make sense. Place all the similarities in your parent class's `init` function and do the following in your child class's `init`.

```
class MyDivision(MyTerm):
    def __init__(self, n, d):
        super(MyDivision, self).__init__()
        self.numerator = n
        self.denominator = d
```

`super()` will execute the parent class's init function.

Also, i don't think it's confusing to use a function here. If you name it well enough, it wouldn't cause confusion.

`term = create_new_term("2")`

Answer (score 0):

I would say a cleaner approach will be define a `Parser` class which takes in the term in it's constructor, and has a `parseTerm` function which returns the class instance to call.

```
class Parser:

    def __init__(self, term):
        self.term = term

    def parseTerm(self):

        matches = re.match(r'^[0-9]+$', self.term)
        if matches is not None:
            return MyNum(self.term)

        matches = re.match(r'^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$', self.term)
        if matches is not None:
            return MyDivision(matches[1], matches[2])
```

Then calling the correct `MyTerm` class will be as simple as:

```
terms = ["2", "2/3"]
for term in terms:
    obj = Parser(term).parseTerm()
    print(obj.latex())
```

And the output is :

```
2
\frac { 2 } { 3 }
```

We can see that it becomes much simpler now that we have delegated everything to `Parser`. We can add conditions to parseTerm for more `MyX` classes and get the objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would factor out the possible matches and use named match groups instead:

```
valid_terms = [{'regex': r'^(?P<n>[0-9]+)$', 'class': MyNum},
               {'regex': r'^(?P<n>[0-9]+)/(?P<d>[0-9]+)$', 'class': MyDivision}]

def parseTerm(term):
    for valid_term in valid_terms:
        match = re.match(valid_term['regex'], term)
        if match is not None:
            return valid_term['class'](**match.groupdict())

    raise ValueError(f'{term} is not a valid term.')
```